# Simultaneously assign many instances' properties

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = None
```

I need to do:

```
[foo1.prop, foo2.prop, ..., fooN.prop] = [prop_value1, prop_value2, ..., prop_value3]
```

Obviously, `N` is not the same always, so I should do it dynamically. The first approach is do it with a for loop:

```
for foo, value in zip(foo_list, value_list):
    foo.prop = value
```

But the question is... Is there a better approach in Python? I mean higher performance.

By the way, `N > 1000`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could do better than a loop. You are always going to need to iterate through the list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman when you do [a, b] = [1, 2] you don't loop anything

Comment: Er, yes. How is that in any way relevant?

Comment: N > 1000 does not sound large at all and your current approach looks fine, just ensure `foo_list` and `value_list` are always the same length

Comment: I would look into refactoring in a way that you don't need so many instances rather one instance that holds an array of objects.

Comment: @MotKohn I can't sinse the value_list is created from a complex multiprocessing process

Comment: This is the correct approach imho. Have you timed this and realized it is a bottleneck?

Comment: Cristhian Boujon. Yes you can. You can insert the instances (or their `prop` property) in an array/queue. This is screaming for an array solution. And/or you can refactor the complex multiprocessing process into returning an array(/queue/whatever). Python [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) is threadsafe, you know. Anyway as written, your object is just a naked wrapper for a single property anyway. You really need to give a more non-trivial motivating example to justify why your process can't return an array or queue. Currently you have shown no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*Is there a better approach in Python? I mean higher performance.*"

I don't believe there is. Let's do a few timed experiments. First, consider an alternative way of performing your assignment: You can use a setter for your class, and call that setter inside a comprehension/map.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = None
    def setProp(self, prop):
        self.prop = prop
```

Now, you can do this:

```
from functools import partial
f = partial(Foo.setProp)

fooList = [...]
propList = [...]

list(map(f, fooList, propList))
```

This works as expected. We can use `timeit` to get some timed results with `N = 1000`:

1. *For loop approach*

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 95.8 µs per loop

2. *Map approach*

> 1000 loops, best of 3: 199 µs per loop

Conclusion: It seems that the timings differ by a factor of 2. I believe that nothing can beat a for loop for this particular use case, it's a syntax of the language and faster than using any function.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Much better. It goes to show that sometimes the simple, readable approach is the best.

Answer (score -1):

One way you might get some improvement is assuming that you save your class variables already into a python-compatible dict (think pickle). Then you can do do something similar to

```
Foo.__dict__ = loaded_dict_value
```

This might be faster than your proposed method due to the fact that

```
Foo.value = loaded_value
```

Is equivalent to `Foo.__dict__['value'] = loaded_value`. This means one more search (For the memory location of 'value' in __dict__. However I don't suspect you will gain much performance out of this.

Comment: Wait, `Foo.__dict__` is the *class* dictionary, not the one for the instance.

Comment: True. I was looking to explicitly show type of the instance. 

foo_instance.__dict__ will give you the parameters contained within the instance.